# pass value from child (login modal) to parent not work

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to get the username from the token from login component (login component is the child of navbar component) and pass it to the parent to show it in navbar like hello USERNAME! .i tried this but I get no value according to my code `huser` public variable should have username value but its empty and not show
note I'm using logincomponent as modal

any idea?

```
<div class="wrapper" (theuser)="getuser($event)">
  <form class="col s12" novalidate #f="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(f)">
    <p>ورود کنید</p>
    <div class="">
      <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red lighten-1 white-text"
              (click)="authenticatea()"><i class="ion-social-googleplus right" style="font-size: 25px"></i>signin
      </button>
      <button class="btn">aaaa</button>
    </div>


    <label for="username">نام کاربری</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="username"
      class="validate"
      placeholder="username"
      required
      autofocus
      [(ngModel)]="user.username"
      name="username"
      #username="ngModel"
      minlength="3"
    >
    <div class="red" *ngIf="username.errors?.required && username.touched">
      username required
    </div>
    <div class="red" *ngIf="username.errors?.minlength && username.touched">
      username must at least 2 character!
    </div>
    <label for="inputPassword">کلمه عبور</label>
    <input
      type="password"
      id="inputPassword"
      class="validate"
      placeholder="Password"
      required
      [(ngModel)]="user.password"
      name="password"
      #password="ngModel"
    >
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.errors?.required && password.touched">
      password required
    </div>
    <div>
      <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
      <label for="test6">ذخیره اطلاعات ورودی</label>
    </div>
    <div class="red-text" *ngIf="error"><p style="font-weight: bold;">{{ error }}</p></div>
    <br>
    <div>
      <button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">ورود</button>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

this is login component ts file

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


  public user = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  };

  public error;

  @Output() theuser = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private router: Router,
              public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<LoginComponent>) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit({value, valid}) {
    if (!valid) {
      console.log("form in invalid!");
    }
    let username = value.username;
    let password = value.password;

    this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8000/login/", {username: username, password: password})
      .subscribe(
        user => {
          console.log(user);
          if (user && user.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(user.token));
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

            let payload = decode(token);

            this.theuser.emit(payload.username);
            this.dialogRef.close();
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
          }
        }, err => {
          this.error = err.error.non_field_errors;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

my navbar component file (parent of login):

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {


  public huser;
  public user = {
    username: ''
  };

  constructor(private http: AuthUserService,
              private userInfoHttp: HttpClient,
              private  router: Router,
              public modal: MatDialog) {


  }


  openLoginModal() {
    let dialogRef = this.modal.open(LoginComponent, {
      height: '400px',
      width: '600px',
    });

  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return this.http.isAuthenticated()

  }


  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngOnChanges() {

  }

  logout() {
    this.http.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);

  }



 getuser(event) {
    this.huser =  event
  }

}
```

Comment: You have not used the `emit()` method on the `EventEmitter`

Comment: yes my mistake .. i correct it but still dont have the value ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MatDialog`](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) has an `afterClosed` observable which can be used to get data from the modal. When you close the modal, invoke the `close` method with the data like this:

*(modal component)*

```
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>) {}    

onSubmit({value, valid}) {
  if (!valid) { console.log('form invalid'); }
  const username = value.username;
  const password = value.password;
  this.dialogRef.close({username, password});
}
```

Then in your parent component, subscribe to the `afterClosed` observable on the dialogRef and make your request in the body of that subscription:

*(login component)*

```
openLoginModal() {
  let dialogRef = this.modal.open(LoginComponent, {
    height: '400px',
    width: '600px',
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(({username, password}) => {
    // whatever you need to do with your data
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but since its a modal component i cant use child selector in parent html file so i used `(theuser)="getuser($event)`  in my login component's form .. is it cause of the problem ?

Comment: Ah yes, that would be it. Updating my answer now.